# A slight error hiding the date picker when switching UISwitch to Off

Tags: ios, swift, static, datepicker, tableview

I managed to achieve a simple showing of the UIDatePicker with an additional tableview cell that acts as a tappable cell that shows and hides the **Date picker**

When i click the UISwitch to **On**, it successfully shows the cell with the Date label. When i tap this cell, it successfully shows the date picker.

**Sample of how it shows it**

[image]

**The Problem:**

[image]

Say i change my mind, and decide not to input a date, I toggle the date picker to off and the cell with the tappable UILabel that the shows the date picker hides successfully, the main problem is when I do this, the date picker remains in view so the user would then have to click on and click the cell to hide it. I been working long hours trying to figure this out but perhaps any experienced developers see where i am going wrong? Here is my code for this view controller:

```
   //
   //  ItemTableViewController.swift
   //  Sample App
   //
   //


 import UIKit
 import CoreData

 class ItemTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, IconSelectionDelegate {



  @IBOutlet weak var dueLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var datepicker: UIDatePicker!
  @IBOutlet weak var dateSwitch: UISwitch!





   var showCell = false // added
   var datePickerHidden = true


    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    title  = "Edit"


    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

}






// this new
@IBAction func dateToggle(sender: AnyObject) {


        showCell = !showCell
        tableView.reloadData()


}



@IBAction func datePickerValue(sender: UIDatePicker) {
     datePickerChanged()

}
func datePickerChanged () {

    dueLabel.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(datepicker.date, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle)
}

// MARK: TableView

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    // Implementation of hidding and showing the picker view

  //        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3 {
  //            
  //            toggleDatepicker()
  //            print("Selected Section 2 Desired cell")
  //            
  //            
  //        } else {
  //            print("You tapped section \(indexPath.section) and row \(indexPath.row)")
   //        }


       if dateSwitch.on == true{
        print("Its on")

        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3 {

            toggleDatepicker()
            print("Selected Section 2 Desired cell. section \(indexPath.section) and row \(indexPath.row)")


        } else {
            print("You tapped section \(indexPath.section) and row \(indexPath.row)")

        }

    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    //        if datePickerHidden && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4 {
    //            return 0
    //        }
    //        else {
    //            return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    //        }

    if datePickerHidden && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4 {
        return 0
    }

    else if 3 == indexPath.row && indexPath.section == 0  {

        return showCell ? 44 : 0;

    } else {

        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath);
    }


}

 func toggleDatepicker() {

    datePickerHidden = !datePickerHidden

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

  }

   // Core data ... and other things irrelevant...


  // ...

  }
```

Comment: You are changing state of local variable datePickerHidden  of class not of hidden property of UIDatePicker, In your case you have to do cell.clipsToBounds = Yes in cellForIndexPath. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the UIDatePicker explicitly on toggling the switch off.

```
@IBAction func dateToggle(sender: AnyObject) {


    showCell = !showCell
    if !showCell {
       datePicker.hidden = true
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
```

}

Comment: Works somehow but as soon as the picker is hidden, it leaves a blank table cell the size of the picker. Anyway this can also be hidden along with the picker ?

Comment: Do you have the datePicker on a UIView?

Comment: The date picker is on a cell embedded from storyboard. The cell is about the size of 80 in height so the UIPicker is set to its cell size approximately. So when the picker disappears when toggled on, the cell itself remains at its height size of 80 blank while the datePicker is hidden

Comment: Then also use tableView's delegate method to resize cell. Instead I would advice you to have datePicker on the viewController's view instead of the cell.